# How to say cut a packet horizontally/vertically/diagonally?

Tags: phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

Let's say I am holding a chips packet and I have to cut it with scissors.

How do I say these 3 expression without the sort of mathematical terms(horizontal, vertical, diagonal)

1: Cut it **horizontally**( at the top). 
Should I say cut it flat?

2: Cut it **diagonally** (at the end.)

3: Cut it **vertically**(on the side)

Comment: It is not your question, but at least in the western US I have not heard *chips packet* (I assume you mean like potato chips). We would say a *bag of chips*.

Comment: Or you could open your chips like the Crazy Russian Hacker: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QY1tLseAZQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say:

> 1: Cut it **across the top**.
>
> 2: Cut it **at one corner**.
>
> 3: Cut it **along the side**.

Comment: "At one corner" could be taken to mean "cut the corner off" or "cut in any direction starting at one corner" (and presume the diagonal cut starts at the corner in the first place). It would be clearer to simply stay with "diagonally". Similarly, "horizontal" and "vertical" may not necessarily be at the top or the side (you can cut horizontally across the middle), depending on what the OP's intent is. The words "horizontally", "diagonally", and "vertically" capture all of these ideas quite cleanly, they are difficult to explain without becoming verbose.

Comment: @JasonC Understood, but the question specifically says without the words (horizontal, vertical, diagonal).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't attempting to correct you, just adding a note for a reader. I read the original question as fundamentally believing horizontal/vertical/diagonal were too mathematically-inclined for every day usage.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for the explanation. I understand it.